# How to make a decent hair scalp so that the hair from it does not go through body?

Tags: particles, hair, collision, shrinkwrap

[image: The hair goes through the body]
**Method I**: make a scalp and generate hair from the scalp. But the problem is that the hair will go through the body. And enabling Deflect Emitter or Collision on the body does not solve this problem.

How to reproduce this problem?

1. sculpt a simple body with a ball-like head;
2. make a mesh surface with all quads;
3. use Mirror modifier and Shrinkwrap modifier to stick this mesh surface to the head as a hair base or scalp;
4. use Blender particle system to generate hair from the hair base;
5. in the Particle Edit mode, comb the hair in the downward direction, so that you see the hair goes through the body.

[image: The hair does not go through the body]

**Method II**: Instead of using that simple mesh surface as hair base, just directly do weight painting on the head, and consequently, in the Particle Edit mode, combing the hair in the downward direction does not make the hair go through the body.

However, this **Method II** of generating hair directly from the head has a serious limitation, because I have to do retopology upon my sculpted head before make any decent hair. In comparison, the **Method I** offers much more flexibility and efficiency - without retopology, just Shrinkwrap the scalp with hair on any head (say 100 heads with different faces), and can be done in minutes.

---

**UPDATE on 01 Apr 2021**:

Since an member reported that no such problem was encountered, I have reproduced the problem by the **Method I**, and you can download my file here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1d4aei5xu2x87z/Hair_problem-2.blend?dl=0

And in this example, Hair Dynamics is enabled, but the problem remains.

Comment: I do not encounter this problem at all. Is hair dynamics enabled on the particle system?

Comment: You did not encounter this problem at all? I am really puzzled. Could you please post your example or a screenshot which demonstrates that no such problem occurs? If really no such problem occurs, then I'll mark your post as the solution. And BTW, in both methods, hair dynamics is not enabled, because this is not hair simulation. However, if I remember correctly, the problem remains even if hair dynamics is enabled. (In Method II, without hair dynamics, the hair does not go thru the body.)

Comment: An example (with Hair Dynamics enabled) was added to the main post, and you can download the file from the Dropbox link above. Thanks!

Comment: Hair dynamics allows hair to respond to the collision system when the animation plays.

Comment: This is not an animation. But it is to comb the hair in the Particle Edit mode. Enabling Hair Dynamics does not prevent hair to go thru the body when combing.

Comment: In that case, I don’t think the problem is your scalp, but rather how the comb tool works.

Comment: Hair dynamics only take effect during playback, but you can play it back then pause it to do a still render (I’ve done that a lot recently).

Comment: In Method II, comb tool has a function called Deflect Emitter, which prevents hair from going thru the body when combing. In Method I, after a scalp is created, the Deflect Emitter only prevents hair from going thru the scalp, but can go thru the body. BTW, using playback along with hair dynamics makes the problem more complicated, since playback messes up the initial hair shape.